# Is it possible retrieve Outlook RPC call data with the Outlook encryption option still enabled?

Tags: outlook, rpc, outlook-2010, mapi

Outlook 2010 / Windows 7 (32-bit)

I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue involving extra MAPI/RPC calls getting generated in Outlook when an add-in is enabled. I'd like to see the raw RPC data going back and forth however the Exchange server team requires the Outlook connection to be encrypted (under **File -> Account Settings -> Email (tab) -> Change... (button) -> More Settings (button) -> Security (tab) -> Encryption (section)**).  If I try disabling Outlook encryption, Outlook can't connect to Exchange at all (and as such, I can't test to reproduce the issue).

Are there debug switches/tools I can enable on the workstation side to get this RPC info? I see that Outlook has a debugging option but I didn't see the RPC data in the debug log directory when it was enabled (perhaps I overlooked it).

Comment: What is the exact problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko When an Outlook add-in is enabled, significantly more MAPI/RPC traffic is generated between Outlook and Exchange and I'm trying to find out why. The add-in itself doesn't have the capability to directly initiate RPC calls.

Comment: Can you step through the code in your addin to see which lines cause the increase?